# Video/Audio Processing:Adding Second Language Sound To 4k video Through Vlc player Result Into Shaky Sound & Video

Tags: video, audio, video-editing, audio-editing, vlc

I Watch Couple Of Videos On Adding Second Language Sound & Adding Subtitle through Vlc Player Cause I Got A Full Web Series Which In Good 4k Video Quality But Only Available In English Sound On The Other Hand I Also Got Some Downgrade Video's Of Same Series With Only Second Language
Problem Is Storing Both Separately IS Not Efficient Choice So What i Did I Extract Only Second Language Sound From Downgraded Quality And Downloaded Subtitle From OpenSubtitle.org
For Respective File And Tried To Merge All This So The Main 4k Video Can Give Me Support Of English Sound,Second Language Sound And Subtitle As well But When I Put Files Through Process of It Using Vlc To Make It New Files Of All Video With High End Video And Both Sound plus Subtitle

1. It is taking too much time to process
2. the end result of this vlc process giving a very shaky/laggy video as well as sound
   the quality has not been droped but the rate of flow of frames i.e. the speed is been
   degraded i tried to increase/ decrese frame rate from the setting given and repeating
   the process but this hardwork is not getting me true results
3. also the output video rate ,audio rate of english, second languge audio rate
   all are differing it is not that easy to fasten up speed of overall video
   as if video is going good english audio is not coming on tym
   if i change this second language sound is not coming on tym
   yes i am playing one audio at a tym
   and if you think it only limited to audio not subtitle is also shaky to appear
   but flucuating it not giving me true result of overall video

i couldn't post videos here to show the o/p but  what i required from you guys is to
give sofware recommendation to solve this problem if you ever encounter it or you dignosed the cause of it
pls provide open source software not like fancy adobe premier pro which cost way much than you  can't afford plus size also should be low not like 20 gb,50gb piece of code
have to be installed on machine as i have not got the powerhouse
i have decent machine with i7 6th gen 4 core with 8 gigs ram and 4gigs of graphics memory
AMD So please provided feasible video processing sofwares
also if there is some online website which can do this stuff recommendation is appreciated

Comment: Do you know what dot (`.`) is for?

Comment: (.mp4) both 4k one and downgraded one same extension

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ffmpeg` to add second audio stream in video. The command will be something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i audio.dts -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
```

For more details you can check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1140567/409497)